# Cant explain why "55" is converted to "7"

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    v := "55"
    if s, err := strconv.Atoi(v); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(v)) // 55
        fmt.Println(s)         // 55
        fmt.Println(string(s)) // 7
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8V1npFiC9iH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`s` is an integer with the value 55, which is the ASCII (and UTF-8) encoding of the character `"7"`. That's what's printed from the last statement.

Answer (score 6):

When you call `s, err := strconv.Atoi("55")` you turn `s` into an integer. When you do `string(s)` afterwards, you're asking for a string that contains the character represented by that integer.

That character happens to be `'7'`. Try `v := "65"` and you'll get `'A'`, etc.